# Label not display in subview of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, label, subview

I am designing an iOS hamburger menu with a table view in swift3

I want to display the number of notifications in menu tab.

```
 let pieNotifi = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width-40, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2-7, 30, 20))
            let pieLabNotifi = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width-40, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2-7, 30, 20))

            let subviews = self.view.viewWithTag(100001)
            if myGlobal.unreaddot != 0 {     //just a count for notifcaiton
                if subviews == nil {

                    pieNotifi.tag = 100001;
                    cell.addSubview(pieNotifi)
                    let pieShape = pieNotifi.layer;
                    pieShape.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                    pieShape.cornerRadius = pieShape.bounds.width / 4

                    pieLabNotifi.textColor = UIColor.white
                    pieLabNotifi.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
                    pieLabNotifi.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
                    pieLabNotifi.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                    pieNotifi.addSubview(pieLabNotifi)
                    pieLabNotifi.text = String(myGlobal.unreaddot)

                }
                else{
                    pieLabNotifi.text = String(myGlobal.unreaddot)
                }

            }else{
                let subviews = cell.viewWithTag(100001)
                subviews?.removeFromSuperview()
                print("remove red dot")
            }
```

however,  it only display the red colour layer but do not have the label. refer to the picture shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K9rp.png)

I had tried to set

```
 .sendSubview(to back:)
 .bringSubview(toFront: )
 .layer.zPosition = 1
```

all these key word not work for me.

Can anyone advise me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the issue is with the positions of your label. You are giving your label x coordinate as cell.contentView.frame.size.width-40, but you want to add it inside the red image view. Changing the x position and y position to 0 (or whatever value you need )for your label will solve your problem. I have modified your code accordingly :

let pieNotifi = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width-40, cell.contentView.frame.size.height/2-7, 30, 20))
            let pieLabNotifi = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 30, 20))

```
        let subviews = self.view.viewWithTag(100001)
        if myGlobal.unreaddot != 0 {     //just a count for notifcaiton
            if subviews == nil {

                pieNotifi.tag = 100001;
                cell.addSubview(pieNotifi)
                let pieShape = pieNotifi.layer;
                pieShape.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                pieShape.cornerRadius = pieShape.bounds.width / 4

                pieLabNotifi.textColor = UIColor.white
                pieLabNotifi.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
                pieLabNotifi.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
                pieLabNotifi.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                pieNotifi.addSubview(pieLabNotifi)
                pieLabNotifi.text = String(myGlobal.unreaddot)

            }
            else{
                pieLabNotifi.text = String(myGlobal.unreaddot)
            }

        }else{
            let subviews = cell.viewWithTag(100001)
            subviews?.removeFromSuperview()
            print("remove red dot")
        }
```

Also try to see your label position in UiDebugger , you might discover that label is added at wrong position.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding subview to UITableView. According to your code you are adding a subview to the cell of UITableView.
Try to add the subview to the content view of the cell, like:

```
    cell.contentView.addSubView(pieNotifi)
```

Comment: Sorry Jitendra, this solution not solve my issue. my red colour pie layer is able to display. On the top of that layer, I expect a label displayed, which cannot display currently